# AngularJS: what are the recommended practices for data formatting?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In an AngluarJS app, I've a data populated table, and want a cell to not display the raw data but a formatted version of it, actually a link to a web page, with an url using the raw data. In other words, something like:

```
<td><a href="http//www.website.com/[RAW_DATA]">[RAW_DATA]</A></td>
```

I see 4 ways to achieve that:

- 1: include the link in the template using something like this :

  ```
  <td><a href="http//www.website.com/{{raw_data}}">{{raw_data}}</A></td>
  ```
- 2: using a custom directive, like this :

  JS

  ```
  directive('custom_link', function() {
      return{
          restrict: 'E',
          template:'<a href="http//www.website.com/{{raw_data}}">{{raw_data}}</A>'
      }
  });
  ```

  HTML

  ```
  <td><custom_link /></td>
  ```
- 3: using a custom filter, like this :

  JS

  ```
  filter('custom_link', function() {
      return function(raw_data) {
          return "http//www.website.com/"+raw_data;
      };
    })
  ```

  HTML

  ```
  <td><a href="{{raw_data|custom_link}}">{{raw_data}}</A></td>
  ```
- 4: using a custom directive AND a custom filter, like this:

  JS

  ```
  directive('custom_link', function() {
      return{
          restrict: 'E',
          template:'<a href="{{raw_data|custom_link_filter}}">{{raw_data}}</A>'
      }
  });

  filter('custom_link_filter', function() {
      return function(raw_data) {
          return "http//www.website.com/"+raw_data;
      };
    })
  ```

  HTML

  ```
  <td><custom_link /></td>
  ```

Which "solution" is the most "elegant", or "AngularJS compliant"?

Thanks

Comment: Just one somewhat related note - use ngHref for links with angular expressions.

Comment: Thanks all of you for your advices and answers.

The example I gave here was very simple, I thought it will be more "readable", but it may have influenced many of you to choose the first "solution". I will think about another example ;)

Answer (score 5):

I always try and subscribe to the **KISS (keep it simple)** principle, if you don't need the more complected solutions and a simpler one provides the needed functionality, use it.

Given that each of the above solutions work or rather give you the needed outcome.

1. I would prefer **Solution 1** as it is easier to read and understand.
2. **Solution 2** is basically the same approach as solution 1, but would be a better solution if you need the same functionality in a number of places or you want something more expandable in the future. **Directives are great for code reuse.**
3. I personally would not use **solutions 3 and 4** as they are more complicated then I feel is needed for what you are describing in the question.

If however you need more complicated data formatting then a filter would be the correct choice. So basically, it comes down to what you are needing to accomplish that determines the correct implementation, but the simplest is usually the best.

Answer (score 1):

- 1,2 Use a directive for creating **reusable** HTML components. Always. If reuse is not your goal for this usecase, then try to Keep it simle (KISS)
- 3,4,5 They all work but make sure that you are gaining something with the added complexity. Added complexity with no added advantage is just not worth the hassle.